# Which function extracts the HTML parameters while reading the feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I am not a wordpress expert. And I am trying to get working auto blogging plugins, I tried **wp-o-matic** and **auto blog**. I noticed the HTML from the feed specially parameters like `class` and `id` from the feed `description` are stripped down just plain tags. Like

```
<div class="someclass">
     some class
</div>
```

is stripped down to

```
<div>
    some class
</div>
```

Which function of wordpress does this and how to prevent it from doing?